# Edit image itself

Tags: images, media, media-library

In the back end in media library when i edit image it allows me to edit almost every thing except the image it self or the image source, so how to change the image source without changing the id of it ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no default way to do this, but this popular plugin solves the issue for most people. I have no connection to the creators of this free plugin, but I've used it on several sites. https://wordpress.org/plugins/enable-media-replace/